# cakephp pass a variable to the view

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to add a column that is the sum of the val_max column in the database

function controller

```
function admin_affiche() {
      $this->Part->recursive = 1;
      $parts = $this->Part->find('all', array(

       ));
      $totalvals = $this->Part->Market->find('first', array(
               array('fields' => array('sum(Market.val_max) AS valtotal'))));

      $this->set('valtotal', $totalvals);
      $this->set('parts', $parts);

   }
```

view

```
<td class="tg-031e"><?php $totalvals[0]['valtotal'] ?></td>
```

the error is **Undefined variable: totalvals**

pass variavle to view

Comment: I can't pass variable to controller please help me

Comment: i use $this->set('parts', $totalvals);

Answer (score 1):

Use `$valtotal` in the view, not `$totalvals`.

You are passing `$valtotal` with this code `$this->set('valtotal', $totalvals);`

If you do `echo pr($valtotal);` in your view, you will print the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `debug()` on the following to see what it is passing to your view, if `debug = 2` is set. Else just use `print_r`.

```
<?php print_r($valtotal); ?>
```

You just have to keep in mind that the first parameter in `set()` is the variable that is passed to the view.

And in your case the variable passed is not `$totalvals` but `$valtotal`.

Comment: i change that function    `function admin_index() {
      $this->Market->recursive = 2;
      $parts = $this->Market->find('all');
      $valtotals = $this->Market->find('all', array(
       array('fields' => array('sum(Market.val_max )  AS ctotal') )));
       echo $valtotals;
       $this->set('valtotals', $valtotals);
      $this->set('markets', $this->paginate(),$parts);
   }`

Comment: same result array not sum val_max

Comment: Look in array and get the result from it.... `echo $valtotal[0]['valtotal']` or print your array here and I can try to help you...

Comment: HI i USE THE CODE ::   ` $totalvals = $this->Market->find('all',array('fields'=>array
('SUM(Market.val_max) as total')));
$this->set(compact('purchaseorders','totalvals')); `

Comment: in view :  print_r($totalvals); the resule is: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [total] => 10 ) ) )